# issue with the preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have used the code

```
$des = "/**   * @description here is the description  *  *  * */";

preg_match('/@description(.*?)\*/', $des, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

For core php file it works fine.

but when I try same in the cakephp view then this do not work.

In cakephp view I used it as:

```
preg_match_all('/@description(.*?)\*/', $commentForClass, $match);
pr($match);
```

But here $match returns an empty array.

Can anyone give me solution??

Comment: Does `$commentForClass` contain newlines? If so, add the `m` modifier.

Comment: Are `$des` and `$commentForClass` the same? Did you reproduce the bug with the description you're giving here? Is your description actually multiline?

Comment: This is not CakePHP related, it is simple PHP. It doesn't matter in what context you use it. It stays always the same. I removed the wrong tag.

Comment: Yes **Halcyon** the string has newline. Can you please revise my preg_match function with modifications.

Comment: Please update your example in your question, the newlines are causing your trouble. Also, if you want to ping someone in the comment, use @Halcyon

Comment: @Halcyon: the m modifier (multiline mode) only changes the meaning of anchors `^` and `$`, but has no effect on the dot. The s modifier (singleline mode) allows the dot to match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all('/@description(.*?)\*/m', $commentForClass, $match);`

`m` is multiline modifier with it matches of ^ and $ are per line not per whole input (default).

You might want to support all case variants using `i` modifier.

For testing regex use [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) or more sophisticated [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) or the ultimate tool [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) (paid, free small plan).